# Extracting Embedded <span> then again <span> data in Python using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get '5 days ago' from this
*Actual data look like this*

```
<div class="C(#959595) Fz(11px) D(ib) Mb(6px)" data-reactid="11">
<span>Zacks</span>
<i aria-hidden="true" class="Mx(4px)">•</i>
<span>5 days ago</span>
</div>
```

when run this

`soup.find('div', {"class": "C(#959595) Fz(11px) D(ib) Mb(6px)"})`

i'm getting this

`<div class="C(#959595) Fz(11px) D(ib) Mb(6px)" data-reactid="11">Zacks</div>`

Please tell me how to get span text ie.. "5 days ago"

Comment: According to the elements you have pasted above, this should work `soup.select('.Mb\(6px\) span')[-1].text`.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly find the css selector for your `5 days ago` span. Just right click on it, click on inspect element. When the inspection tool opens right click and go to copy menu and there copy css selector.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''
<div class="C(#959595) Fz(11px) D(ib) Mb(6px)" data-reactid="11">
<span>Zacks</span>
<i aria-hidden="true" class="Mx(4px)">•</i>
<span>5 days ago</span>
</div>
'''
doc  = SimplifiedDoc(html)
# Use <i> to locate
text = doc.getElement('div',value='C(#959595) Fz(11px) D(ib) Mb(6px)').getElement('i',value='Mx(4px)').getNext('span').text
print (text)
# Take the last one
text = doc.getElement('div',value='C(#959595) Fz(11px) D(ib) Mb(6px)').spans[-1].text
print (text)
```

Result:

```
5 days ago
5 days ago
```